# How to return two pdf files in one action result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I need to return two PDF files on postback in MVC, but the action result is returning only one file. Is there any other way is there to return more than one file in an action result?

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf", Summary.pdf);
```

Like this I need to return more than one file.

Comment: provide two hrefs on view and user can download by clicking it

Comment: Zip them up into a single file, merge the PDFs or provide two links. Anything else is just weird UI.

Comment: Friend i need submit my form then only i can able to do some calculation to generate reports

Comment: what is zip i dont know about that friend can you show me some example

Comment: zip, rar, tar, 7z now you know?

Answer (score 5):

An `ActionResult` returned from an action in a controller always represents one thing, and since there is no concept of multi-file references in HTML, you have to make two separate steps, or merge the existing action in one step.

So you have three options:

- Create two hyperlinks, with two separate actions to call. Generate a report in either of them. Return a `FileResult` like you do now.
- Put your files in a zip file, and send that one over. The nice thing is that you only need one action. The bad thing is that users have to unzip the file before they can view the report. To make this work, you first have to generate both documents, use a [library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to zip the files, and then return that using a `FileResult` or a stream.
- Merge the two reports into one. If this is feasible depends if the documents are that related they can be considered one. You can use a [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to merge them together and send back the merged report.

My bet would be on option 1 unless you have very good reasons not to do so.

Comment: how o put my files in zip in c#

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for example.

Comment: You can also merge the PDFs using a library like iTextSharp, but I think that's overkill - just use option 1.

Comment: Depends if you can consider them one. If you have two separate documents you might want to keep it that way. It is a good third option I think. @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

if you use ajax , you can create file links and send back link with json and then open links in javascripts.

server side:

```
 ...
    retrun Json(new {.link1 = "stackoverflow.com" , 
                     .link2 = "stackexchange.com"})
```

and client side :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ActionName" , "ControllerName")",
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function(sucess) {
            if(success.link1 != undefined)
            {
                  var win = window.open(d.link1 , '_blank');
                  var win1 = window.open(d.link2 , '_blank');
                  if (win==undefined) {
                      //Broswer has blocked it
                      alert(' Activate your browser popup');
                  }
            }
       },
       error: function () { console.log("error"); }
  });
```